# NSUserDefaults working on simulator but not working on Device (get nil)!

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, xcode6

I have a problem between container app and extension app by using *NSUserDefaults.* Its working fine on simulator but not working on devices (crashed). i'm writing in swift.

In my container app

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myapp")
    defaults.setValue(label1.text, forKey: "Textview")
    defaults .synchronize()
  }
```

in my extension app

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myapp")  
     var string : String = defaults.valueForKey("Textview") as String //Crashed on device   
     label2.text = "\(string)"    //get nil
 }
```

I get crashed after running on my device but working on simulator, please help!Thanks

Comment: Did you register your defaults first via `registerDefaults`? This way you define default settings when no value was saved before.

Answer (score 0):

1> clean your project and after run it
2>

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.myapp")
   defaults.setObject(label1.text,forKey: "GameData")
   defaults.synchronize()
}
```

getting data :

```
if let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() {
        if let str : AnyObject = defaults.objectForKey("GameData") {
            println(str)
        }
    }
```

3>

```
var myValue:NSString = label1.text
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myValue, forKey:"Username")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

getting data:

```
var myOutput: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username")
println(myOutput)
```

I think this help you.